# AJAX request not working as expected

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery AJAX function but not only does it not run, it blocks other js functions too, like PrettyPhoto. Even the `$("#cookie-bar").hide(1000);` doesn't run. Where is my mistake?

```js
function getresult(newid) {
  var oldid = newid;
  if (oldid != "") {
    var idnum = oldid + 1;
  } else {
    var idnum = <? PHP echo $last_idh; ?> ;
  }
  $.ajax({
    url: "getresult.php?idh=" + idnum + "&mese=<?PHP echo $mese; ?>",
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
      var mydata = html;
      var txtloaded = mydata.split('§');
      var scheda = txtloaded[0];
      var num = txtloaded[1];
      $("#schedules").append(scheda);
    },
    error: function() {}
    loadData(num);
  });
}

function loadData(nextid) {
  var next = nextid;
  setTimeout(function() {
    getresult(next);
  }, 1000);
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
  $("#cookie-bar").hide(1000);
  loadData();
});
```

I have done some correction, so the code now is:

```js
function getresult(newid) {
 var idnum = newid + 1;
 $.ajax({
  url: "getresult.php?idh="+idnum+"&mese=<?PHP echo $mese; ?>",
  type: "GET",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
  var mydata = html;
  var txtloaded = mydata.split('§');
  var scheda = txtloaded[0];
  var num = txtloaded[1];
  $("#schedules").append(scheda);
  },
  error: function(){}
  loadData(num);
   });
}
function loadData(nextid) {
 var next = nextid;
 setTimeout(function(){
  getresult(next);
 },1000);
}
 
$(window).scroll(function() {
 $("#cookie-bar").hide(1000);
 loadData("<?PHP echo $last_idh; ?>");
});
```

The console say me that the error is here: "loadData(num);". Variable 'num' isn't recognized like value...

Comment: Anything in the error console? What does the "net" tab say about the Ajax request?

Comment: Open your console

Comment: You are calling the `loadData` method inside `window.scroll` without any argument(`next id` I suppose). But the `getresult` only check newId to be "" and not `undefined`

Comment: I have done some correction, so the code now is:

Answer (score 0):

`loadData` is inside `getResult` and therefore it is unreachable from `scroll`. Try to put `loadData` outside `getResult`. The other problem is that you do not pass `newid` when you call `loadData`.

Answer (score 0):

loadData must be instanced with empty value that's the logic of your code

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $("#cookie-bar").hide(1000);
  loadData("");
});
```

Edit

```
error: function(e) {}
    console.log(e);
  });
```

Comment: loadData is inside getResult. That's the main problem.

Comment: remove the loadData in errorfunction and set 
error: function(e) {}
    consol.log(e);
  });